# Spring Boot Liquibase not picking up all application.yml files

Tags: java, spring-boot, liquibase

I have a Spring Boot 1.4.3 project which should load Liquibase on startup. It's ought to be a simple configuration but I've spent a lot of time to get the following working.

Consider a ModuleA (a normal jar) and a ModuleB (a bootstrapped jar). ModuleB has a dependency towards moduleA, so when moduleB starts, moduleA is on it's classpath.

ModuleA contains some generic properties, encoded in an application.yml and some in an application.properties file.
ModuleB also has an application.yml file with more specific properties.

In ModuleA I have defined my Liquibase properties in the application.yml file. One would expect that on startup of ModuleB, the liquibase properties would be available. This however does not work.

If I put the liquibase properties in the application.properties in ModuleA, the properties are picked when ModuleB starts.

**So my question is**: is it impossible to have two 'application.yml' files on the classpath ? I find nothing about it in the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) and in fact, in the first part it mentions that it should be possible:

```
14. Application properties outside of your packaged jar (application.properties and YAML variants).
15. Application properties packaged inside your jar (application.properties and YAML variants).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not possible. There is no composition of several `application.properties` or `application.yml`. That would make things very hard to track. You can check the `/env` endpoint to check what was added to the environment. You can also see which property sources (= which "file") was loaded.

Reading the doc, I realize that indeed you may understand the opposite. Please create an issue to request the doc to be more explicit about it.

Comment: I did a bit more research because it was strange that multiple application.properties work, but it turns out doesn't work. I had 
moduleA/application-dev.properties
moduleB/application.properties

So you're indeed right. I didn't know about the /env url, can be very usefull (but dangerous at the same time).